# Hide selection in webpart - .ms-WPHeaderTdSelection {display:none}

Tags: web-part, css

Hiding the selection is not working.

```
<style type="text/css">

.ms-WPHeaderTdSelection {display:none}

</style>
```

Here is the working code:

```
<style>
/*--------Hide the columns--------*/
.ms-viewheadertr { 
 display: none;
}
/*---------Hide the Add Document option-------*/
.ms-addnew { 
 display: none;
}
/*---------Remove the new image icon on newly added documents-------*/
IMG.ms-newgif {
 display:none;
}
/*---------Hide the web part selection checkbox------*/
.ms-WPHeaderTdSelection
{
display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The above solution worked. But When hover over a record the selection box still shows up. What's the fix for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide it with only css, because it will displayed with javascript on mouseover. Why do you want to hide the webpart context menu? Could it be sufficient to control this [with user permissions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/4d8e51f7-a3a2-46dd-807b-cc8d7b4e72d6/)

> Site Actions-->Site Settings-->Users & Groups and you can edit the
>   permissions..

Or you can remove webpart chrome and this context menu will only appear in Edit Page mode which you also can control with permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following CSS worked for me:

```
.ms-WPHeaderTdSelection
{
    display: none !important;
}
```